# Maven deploy and versions of dependencies

Tags: maven

When I run mvn deploy on a project where the version of a dependency in the child pom is defined as a property in the parent pom, the version number is not expanded in the deployed artifact.

In this example ${spring.version} is not expanded. Can I make maven expand the version property?

**Parent pom:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>TestProject</groupId>
<artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>test</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>dips_snapshot</id>
        <url>http://mavenrepo.dips.local/repository/dips_snapshot</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
</project>
```

**Child pom:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>TestProject</groupId>
<artifactId>subproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>TestProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Deployed pom:**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>TestProject</groupId>
<artifactId>subproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
<groupId>TestProject</groupId>
<artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: I don't get any errors when doing it like this, but if I use a super-pom where I set the version of the dependencies in a property, and then deploy the project, every version of the deployed artifact depends on whats specified in the super-pom.

Comment: The consequence of this is that I sometimes get this error when I'm building other projects dependent on this.

Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:pom:${commons.dbcp.version} from/to springsource-repo (http://repo.springsource.org/release): Illegal character in path at index 64: http://repo.springsource.org/release/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/${commons.dbcp.version}/commons-dbcp-${commons.dbcp.version}.pom

Comment: Is your parent POM being deployed as well (have you run `mvn deploy` on TestProject)?  If not, try that.

Comment: @Thomas are the projects that fail not depending on the super pom and somehow missing on the common.dbcp.version property?

Comment: All the projects are dependent on the super pom, and the property is in the super pom. And the super-pom has been deployed to our company repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to install locally (or even deploy) the parent pom. To do so you can simply run:

```
mvn clean install -N
```

in your parent project directory. The `-N` option is not mandatory, it only stop the recursion (so it will be very fast since only your parent pom will installed)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a different project organization, where parenthood and aggregation are separated. I use an aggregator project which contains my plain projects as modules and a parent project which is also a module of my aggregator project. This parent project is shared between all the plain projects and the aggregator. My parent and plain projects are stored in subdirectories of the aggregator project directory and the `relativePath` of each `parent` element is set accordingly.

This organization better separates concerns and ensures that inter-project dependencies are handled correctly, as long as you perform your builds from the aggregator project directory.